# Array of pointers to different structs

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

It is possible to do something like this [How can I initialize an array of pointers to structs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194828/how-can-i-initialize-an-array-of-pointers-to-structs)
but with different structs?

E.g.

```
static struct structA_t a = {"ads", "as"};
static struct structB_t b = {"zzds", "dfr", "shywsd"};
static struct structC_t c = {"ssa", "ad", "dhksdhs"};

struct some_type *array[] = { &a, &b, &c};
```

How some_type will look like?

Comment: I think you're confused as to what the term "array" means in C.

Comment: array means set of elements of same data type.

Comment: Stating your problem definition as to why you would need such a thing will make this a better question or is just your curiosity?

Comment: C isn't a terribly good fit for this. What you're trying to do is implement a 'bag', and that's crying out for an object-oriented language with run-time polymorphism.

Comment: I just had hope that it is possible to create some set of different structs and arrays with pointers for that structs and another arrays with pointers to members of structs (indexes will be #defined). All that for one function for managing elements of my structs and all in C.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could define `some_type` as a union:

```
typedef union{
  struct structA_t;
  struct structB_t;
  struct structC_t;
}some_type;
```

This will lead you to the problem that you don't know what's actually contained in which element in the array.

To overcome this, add another field specifying the content that is used:

```
/* numbers to identify the type of the valid some_type element */
typedef enum my_e_dataId{
  dataid_invalid = 0,
  dataid_a,
  dataid_b,
  dataid_c
} my_dataId;

typedef union u_data {
  struct structA_t* a;
  struct structB_t* b;
  struct structC_t* c;
}mydata;

typedef struct s_some_type{
  my_dataId dataId;
  mydata    myData;
}some_type;
```

Then you could initialize your array as follows:

```
some_type sta[] = {
  {dataid_a, (struct structA_t*) &a},
  {dataid_b, (struct structA_t*) &b},
  {dataid_c, (struct structA_t*) &c}
};
```

When you loop over the elements of `array`, first evaluate `dataId` so that you know what's contained in `myData`. Then, for example, access the data of the first element using

```
sta[0].myData.a->FIELDNAME_OF_A_TO_ACCESS
```

or the third element with

```
sta[2].myData.c->FIELDNAME_OF_C_TO_ACCESS
```

See this ideone for a working example: http://ideone.com/fcjuR

Comment: Good answer, but swap out the #defines for enums.

Comment: enums are safer.  #define is good at writing over things, including enums, other #defines, and even variable names, whereas enums will produce real compile errors in case of such conflicts.

Comment: `enum {a = 4}; enum {a = 5};`  is a compile error, that's the sort of situation I'm referring to, which is a reason enum is preferred over #define.

Comment: @eckes I realize now that still you have array with only one type of struct. This will not work and this would be the aim (I mean the code below would be the aim): some_type sta[] = {
  {dataid_a, (struct structA_t*) &a},
  {dataid_b, (struct structB_t*) &b},
  {dataid_c, (struct structC_t*) &c}
};

Comment: @bienieck: the cast to `struct structA_t*` is only needed to satisfy the compiler (will yield a warning if not). **Actually**, the data stored in the array is correct. See the ideone: http://ideone.com/fcjuR

Comment: Is there any possibility to use above idea  in function with parameters for determining member of struct? Eg void foo(STRUCT,MEMBER){here will be operation for convertion actual member into array of chars, based for example on memcpy()}

Answer (score 1):

In C this is possible with void pointers (Replace "struct some_type" with "void"), but you really shouldn't be doing this.  Arrays are for programming with homogeneous data.

Comment: As you said, one shouldn't be doing this. How will the person be able to distinguish at which index what type of element is present?

Comment: Well, the switch statement is primitive polymorphism, and it's possible to add a second array of type-enums or wrap in a union with an identifier as in the above answer, but this does literally answer the question.